# QML - Using fmod() in a ShaderEffect?

Tags: qt, qml, glsl

I'm trying to compute a "cyclic offset" in my GLSL shader (i.e. calculate `value + offset` clamped to the `[0, 1]` range).

Currently, I've ended up resorting to a nasty hack involving lots of casting and multiplying/dividing by 100 to make the values integers so that integer-mod (%) works. It looks something like:
    `float x = float(int((qt_TexCoord0.x + timeOffset) * 100.0) % 100) / 100.0`

Two questions:
 1. Is there something like `fmod()` I could use instead?
 2. Is it possible to use `#include's` in GLSL shaders? Or do I need to inline any imports I'd otherwise like to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GLSL provide `mod()` which computes `x-y*floor(x/y)` while HLSL `fmod()` I believe computes `x-y*trunc(x/y)`

https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/mod.xhtml

At the time of writing `#include` preprocessor is not yet available.

https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)